# NetLogo set patches within a specific range

Tags: netlogo

I'm new to stack overflow and netlogo, in fact this is my first question ever. I thank you all in advance.

In netlogo I have created 4 areas to represent 4 office spaces which coincide with quadrants I-IV:

```
to setup-environment
  ask patches with [ pycor mod 2 = 0 and pxcor <= -16]   [ set pcolor grey ]
  ask patches with [ pycor mod 2 = 0 and pxcor >= 16]   [ set pcolor grey ]
  ask patches with [ pxcor mod 2 = 0 and pycor <= -16]   [ set pcolor grey ]
  ask patches with [ pxcor mod 2 = 0 and pycor >= 16]   [ set pcolor grey ]
  ask patches with [ pycor = 0]   [ set pcolor red ]
  ask patches with [ pxcor = 0]   [ set pcolor red ]

  ; THIS PART IN PARTICULAR
  ask patches [
    set a-space patches with [(pxcor < 0) and (pycor > 0)]
    set b-space patches with [(pxcor > 0) and (pycor > 0)]
    set c-space patches with [(pxcor > 0) and (pycor < 0)]
    set d-space patches with [(pxcor < 0) and (pycor < 0)]
  ]
```

This sets up, for example, a-space to be in quadrant II entirely, I need the patches in a-space to be within a certain range. I tried `(-14 < pxcor < 0) and (14 > pycor > 0)` so that the area is within x = (-14, 0) and y (16, 0), but got this error:

> expected this input to be an agent or number or string, but got a
>   TRUE/FALSE instead

I understand that you can't set patches, but that is not what I'm trying to do here, I'm trying set an area with patches with the range I specify.

Comment: I edited your question for formatting - when you write the question, there's some icons above the text entry box that allow you to mark sections as code or quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow (and NetLogo). For future questions, please show the specific code that generates the error as part of your example code. However, if I understand your question correctly, you had something like:

```
set a-space patches with [(-14 < pxcor < 0) and (14 > pycor > 0)]
```

You can't use compound comparisons such as this in NetLogo. The statement `-14 < pxcor < 0` in mathematics is two separate logical statements: `-14 < pxcor` and `pxcor < 0`. You must construct them as two statements and use the logical operator `and` to join them.

Following is a complete model that I think does what you want. Note that as well as the logical structure, I removed your `ask patches`. The way you have your code set up, each patch sets the variables `a-space` etc. So, if you have 2500 patches, then those variables are set (to the same value) 2500 times.

```
globals [a-space b-space c-space d-space]

to setup-environment
  ask patches with [ pycor mod 2 = 0 and pxcor <= -16]   [ set pcolor grey ]
  ask patches with [ pycor mod 2 = 0 and pxcor >= 16]   [ set pcolor grey ]
  ask patches with [ pxcor mod 2 = 0 and pycor <= -16]   [ set pcolor grey ]
  ask patches with [ pxcor mod 2 = 0 and pycor >= 16]   [ set pcolor grey ]
  ask patches with [ pycor = 0]   [ set pcolor red ]
  ask patches with [ pxcor = 0]   [ set pcolor red ]

  ; THIS PART IN PARTICULAR
  set a-space patches with [(-14 < pxcor) and (pxcor < 0) and (pycor > 0) and (pycor < 5)]
  ask a-space [set pcolor blue]
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @JenB this worked. I had tried something similar like this ; THIS PART IN PARTICULAR

  set a-space patches with

 [-14 < pxcor and pxcor < 0 and pycor > 0 and pycor < 5]
  ask a-space [set pcolor blue]

But this didn't work, I had an error message saying "and" could only take 2 arguments or words to that effect. I now see that in order to use multiple "and" statements they must be contained within  parenthesis.